# React Native not rendering prop even though data is available

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props, react-functional-component

I just started a basic React Native app using the template for tabbed view. I need to be able to make a http get request for some data and I used the example from the docs as a starting point. Rendering the  works fine when in the same component. I am trying to create another component for the list item and passing the data as a prop from the parent.

Parent:

```js
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const abortController = new AbortController();
    const signal = abortController.signal;
    fetch("https://reactnative.dev/movies.json", { signal: signal })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json.movies))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));

    return function cleanup() {
      abortController.abort();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Tab Mars One</Text>
      <View
        style={styles.separator}
        lightColor="#eee"
        darkColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.1)"
      />
      {isLoading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator />
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Post item={item} />
          )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Child:

```js
const Post = (item) => {
    console.log(item)
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <View>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

When I run this, nothing renders at all. No console errors. Console logging the item in the Post component is logging the correct items from the API so I know the data is there and correctly formatted but nothing is being rendered. These are the only files I have edited in the project so I'm not sure where the issue is coming from or what I am missing. Please advise.

Comment: Have you verified the `fetch` is successful, i.e. `response.ok` is truthy? State `data` is correctly updated?

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified. The example I used from the docs used <Text>{item.title}</Text>. When I used this, the list renders fine. When I change this to my custom Post component, passing the item as a prop, nothing renders.

Comment: @DrewReese forgot to tag^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You've passed your data to a prop `item`, but in `Post` have name the *entire* props object `item`.

## Solution

`Post` needs to destructure `item` from props.

```
const Post = ({ item }) => {
  console.log(item)
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <View>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

[Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@drew.w.reese/ashamed-scone)

Comment: Ah okay. Simple solution. That worked. New to React and didn't realize React couldn't read an object without destructuring. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @andrewxt `item.item.title` would have worked as well, but a little silly (synonymous to `props.item.title`). It's ok, I didn't catch it either until I'd copied it into an IDE to run it and saw that it didn't look right.

Comment: I see okay. So where I had (item), was actually there as a reference to ALL props. So I had single out the one I needed. That makes sense.

Comment: @andrewxt Yup, exactly.